# Ruby on rails form.select "undefined method"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, drop-down-menu

In an erb file I'm trying to create a drop-down menu and save the selection to the database upon submission. I have this chunk of code:

```
<% form_for my_object do |form|%>

  <% option_pairs = values.map { |val| [val.id, val.id] } %>
  <%= form.select :var_to_save_to, options_for_select(option_pairs) %>

<% end %>
```

However, when I try loading the page I get an error saying `undefined method 'var_to_save_to' for #<MyObjectClass>`

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: can you upload your model schema for this form (my_object)

Comment: var_to_save_to is the attribute of my_object where is gonna be stored the value of the drop-down. So you should check if that attribute exists in your model checking your database

Comment: @OscarLuza How can I check it exists?

Comment: check your database in schema.rb or the migration file, also you can test it with rails console and enter MyObject.new

Comment: @OscarLuza So i checked it with the console, and it definitely doesn't exist.. However it's used in the model, so why does it not exist in the DB? How can I add it to the DB?

Comment: You can create a migration and add such attribute, try with `rails g migration add_attribute_to_model attribute:datatype` tweaking with your needed values.

Comment: Awesome, got it all sorted out. Thanks guys!